# PHP json_encode utf-8 issue on database

Tags: php, json, utf-8

I got a problem. I use `json_encode` and after I upload on a database. My files are in utf8 and my database too. But in my database there is some `\u00e9` and I don't know why ...

EDIT :

There is a simple code :

```
$toast = array();
    for($i=0;$i<11;$i++)
        $toast[]='é';

    $toast = json_encode($toast);
    print utf8_decode($toast);
```

This doesn't work how can I print a simple array full of 'é' character...

EDIT 2 :

This code :

```
$toast = array();
    for($i=0;$i<11;$i++)
        $toast[]='é';

    $toast = json_encode($toast);
    print $toast;
```

OUTPUT:

```
["\u00e9","\u00e9","\u00e9","\u00e9","\u00e9","\u00e9","\u00e9","\u00e9","\u00e9","\u00e9","\u00e9"]
```

And I want :

```
["é","é","é","é","é","é","é","é","é","é","é"]
```

Comment: there is no problems with that, those are unicodes, those are used so that some characters are escaped

Comment: they are escaped by the function? there is no solution for have é instead of \u00e9 in database

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use **`JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE`** flag of `json_encode` (available since PHP 5.4):

```
$toast = json_encode($toast, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

Before PHP 5.4, you can use this snippet:

```
$toast = json_encode($toast);
$toast = preg_replace_callback('/\\\\u([0-9a-f]{4})/i', function($matches) {return mb_convert_encoding(pack('H*', $matches[1]), 'UTF-8', 'UTF-16');}, $toast);
```

As `mb_convert_encoding()` is not available on all installations, you can also use this dirty workaround:

```
$toast = array_map('htmlentities', $toast);
$toast = json_encode($toast);
$toast = html_entity_decode($toast);
```

**But there is *no* problem with `\uXXXX` values - it just looks uglier.**

Comment: I make this :

    $toast = json_encode($toast);
    $toast = preg_replace_callback('/\\\\u([0-9a-f]{4})/i',      function($matches) {return mb_convert_encoding(pack('H*', $matches[1]), 'UTF-8', 'UTF-16');}, $toast);
    echo $toast;


But there is no echo ...

Comment: You can use `var_dump(json_last_error())` after this call to track your JSON errors.

Comment: Added a third solution :)

Comment: Seems like your `error_reporting` is misconfigured on your development server. Please try the third solution.

Comment: OUTPUT OF THIRD SOLUTION :

["Ã©","Ã©","Ã©","Ã©","Ã©","Ã©","Ã©","Ã©","Ã©","Ã©","Ã©"]

Comment: Are you sure that your browser is set to utf-8? `Ã©` is utf-8 `é` interpreted as iso.

Comment: It is good I have solve my problem it was just json_decode() which return a good response . Sorry about that I was afraid by the code \u in my database but json decode work perfectly :)